# Find all possible subsequences of a string with fixed length

Tags: arrays, string, list, algorithm

I got this problem from CodinGame yesterday.

Note: I don't know how to explain this note so I am gonna explain it by the example:
A string "hey" has these subsequences with length 2: "he", "hy" and "ey".

What I tried: I have an idea of a solution but it is a little complicated to actually implement.
The idea is: we make a list with length of required subsequences. We attempt to go through all possible lists, with the aforementioned restrictions. Looping through every possibility of an element with next one is not enough, as there will be missing possible lists.

I think I tried it on my own enough, it's time to ask stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation example in Python, using a recursive function.

```py
def subsequence(text, subseq_length):
  if subseq_length <= 0:
    return []

  if subseq_length == 1:
    return list(text)

  text_length = len(text)
  res = []
  tail_length = subseq_length - 1
  for i in range(0, text_length - tail_length):
    for tail in subsequence(text[i+1:], tail_length):
      res.append(text[i] + tail)
  return res

print(subsequence('hey', 2))
print(subsequence('hello', 3))
```

Output:

```
['he', 'hy', 'ey']
['hel', 'hel', 'heo', 'hll', 'hlo', 'hlo', 'ell', 'elo', 'elo', 'llo']
```

Comment: I missed asking for python specific answer. But you provided it either way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The subsequence (of length `k`) either includes a first letter, or not. In the first case, you want all subsequences of length `k-1` from the rest of the string. In the second case you want all subsequences of length `k`, again from the rest of the string. This observation leads to a simple recursion. In pseudocode,

```
list_subsequences(s, k)
    if len(s) < k or k == 0
        return empty set
    c = first character of s
    s1 = tail of s (first character removed)
    set1 = list_subsequences(s1, k-1)
    prepend c to all strings in s1
    set2 = list_subsequences(s1, k)
    return set1 + set2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations`

```
import itertools

x = list(set(list(itertools.combinations(["h","e","y"] , 2) ) ) )
x = [ "".join(i) for i in x ]
print(x)

>> ['he', 'ey', 'hy']
```

Another example using "hello"

```
x = list(set(list(itertools.combinations(["h","e","l","l","o"] , 2) ) ) )
x = [ "".join(i) for i in x ]
print(x)

>> ['ho', 'lo', 'el', 'eo', 'he', 'll', 'hl']


x = list(set(list(itertools.combinations(["h","e","l","l","o"] , 3) ) ) )
x = [ "".join(i) for i in x ]
print(x)


>> ['heo', 'hlo', 'elo', 'ell', 'hll', 'llo', 'hel']
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I wanted. But I wonder how it would look like with no outside lib.